# Mysql user privileges : Only CREATE table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a user who will be able to manage all databases without the right to  CREATE and DROP databases.

I have been using the following link :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER ON *.* TO 'mysql'@'192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'toto'
```

I would like to add CREATE in order to allow the user to create a table, but If I do this the user will be able to create a database too.

Is it possible to provide CREATE "table" without CREATE "database" privilege ?

Comment: This might better fit [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) but for what I know, the only way is to only grant CREATE privilege on database level (i.e. not grant it on `*.*` but for `database1.*` etc).

Comment: yes so far this is what I did... created a bash wich grant those rights for all databases, I'm not really satisfied with it.

Comment: You could also probably create a stored procedure that does the same thing, then you could still use the SQL prompt for grants (if that is any better option).